# Woocommerce rest api no order returned

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have download the class-wc-api-client.php and create my own php file for getting woocommerce orders data like this:

```
<?php

require_once "class-wc-api-client.php";

$consumer_key = 'ck_090820a4cf77re32737fe80005yyy643';
$consumer_secret = 'cs_38753tr76y3isjr863gerrc6fdabae17e';
$store_url = 'http://www.soralis.net/shop/';

// Initialize the class
$wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );

// Get all orders
$orders = $wc_api->get_orders();
// Output the order object retrieved from the API
print_r( $orders );
?>
```

But this script return 1, a blank $orders (in my ecommerce there are 2 orders in status completed)

i have create in my website root folder named "/wc-api/v1" and placed here my two php files.

Someone can help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to call the api directly? You can get your order by using this function.

```
function get_all_user_orders($user_id,$status='completed'){
    if(!$user_id)
        return false;

    $orders=array();//order ids

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'meta_key'        => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'      => $user_id,
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'tax_query'=>array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  =>'shop_order_status',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     =>$status
                    )
        )  
    );

    $posts=get_posts($args);
    //get the post ids as order ids
    $orders=wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );

    return $orders;
}
```

And then call this function like this

```
$order_ids= get_all_user_orders($user_id , 'processing');
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering client and server communication.
To fetch wooCommerce orders:

1. After doing cart->checkout process, We come across save order and make a payment.
2. Then while save order, post the user, shipping and billing details, nonce for that unique order generated at woocommerce (you can get that on client by making a middleware request).
3. Validate shipping and payment methods

```css
public function save_order( $data ) {
  if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
   define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
  }
  $_POST = $data;  
  $errors = array();
         
        /*check Nonce for every order you are creating with woocommerce checkout*/
  if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-process_checkout' ) ) {
   WC()->session->set( 'refresh_totals', true );
   return $response['messages'] = 'We were unable to process your order, please try again.';
  }

  if ( ! defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ) {
   define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
  }

  // Prevent timeout
  @set_time_limit(0);

  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process' );

  if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
   return $response['messages'] = 'Sorry, your session has expired.';
  }

  do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process' );

  // Checkout fields (not defined in checkout_fields)
  $this->posted['terms']                     = isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ? 1 : 0;
  $this->posted['createaccount']             = isset( $_POST['createaccount'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['createaccount'] ) ? 1 : 0;
  $this->posted['payment_method']            = isset( $_POST['payment_method'] ) ? stripslashes( $_POST['payment_method'] ) : '';
  $this->posted['shipping_method']           = isset( $_POST['shipping_method'] ) ? $_POST['shipping_method'] : array();
  $this->posted['ship_to_different_address'] = isset( $_POST['ship_to_different_address'] ) ? true : false;

  if ( isset( $_POST['shiptobilling'] ) ) {
   _deprecated_argument( 'WC_Checkout::process_checkout()', '2.1', 'The "shiptobilling" field is deprecated. The template files are out of date' );

   $this->posted['ship_to_different_address'] = $_POST['shiptobilling'] ? false : true;
  }

  // Ship to billing only option
  if ( wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() ) {
   $this->posted['ship_to_different_address']  = false;
  }


  $result = $this->update_billing_shipping($data);
  
  if($result['result'] == 'failure') {
   return $result;
  }
  
  if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) {

   if ( ! in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), array_keys( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() ) ) ) {
    $errors[] = 'Unfortunately we do not ship .Please enter an alternative shipping address' ;
   }

   // Validate Shipping Methods
   $packages               = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
   $this->shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

   foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
    if ( ! isset( $package['rates'][ $this->shipping_methods[ $i ] ] ) ) {
     $errors[] = 'Invalid shipping method.';
     $this->shipping_methods[ $i ] = '';
    }
   }
  }

  if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
   // Payment Method
   $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

   if ( ! isset( $available_gateways[ $this->posted['payment_method'] ] ) ) {
    $this->payment_method = '';
    $errors[] = 'Invalid shipping method.';
   } else {
    $this->payment_method = $available_gateways[ $this->posted['payment_method'] ];
    $this->payment_method->validate_fields();
   }
  } else {
   $available_gateways = array();
  }

  // Action after validation
  do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', $this->posted );

  if ( empty( $errors ) ) {

   // Customer accounts
   $this->customer_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_customer_id', get_current_user_id() );

   /*Do a final stock check at this point*/
   wc()->checkout->check_cart_items();

   wc()->checkout->posted = $this->posted;
  
   $order_id = $this->_create_order();

   if ( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ) {
    $response['messages'] = $order_id->get_error_message();
    return $response;
   }

   do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $this->posted );

   // Process payment
   if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
    // Store Order ID in session so it can be re-used after payment failure
    WC()->session->order_awaiting_payment = $order_id;

    // Process Payment
    $result = $available_gateways[ $this->posted['payment_method'] ]->process_payment( $order_id );
    $result['order_id'] = $order_id;
    $result['flag'] = 'true';

    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page
    if ( isset( $result['result'] ) && 'success' === $result['result'] ) {
     $result = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', $result, $order_id );
     return $result;
    }
   } else {
    if ( empty( $order ) ) {
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    // No payment was required for order
    $order->payment_complete();

    // Empty the Cart
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    // Get redirect
    $return_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();

    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page
    return( array(
     'result'  => 'success',
     'redirect'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_no_payment_needed_redirect', $return_url, $order ),
     'order_id' => $order_id,
     'flag'  => 'true'
    ) );
   }
  }

  $response = array(
   'result' => 'failure',
   'messages'  => $errors
  );

  unset( WC()->session->refresh_totals, WC()->session->reload_checkout );

  return $response;
 }
```